# How to add another process after TextIO.write on dataflow pipeline

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, pipeline, dataflow

I created a simple dataflow pipeline which consist of this process:

1. Fetch/read data from bigquery
2. Change the output to csv format
3. Create CSV file on Google Storage
4. //TODO send CSV file to third party

```
pipeline.apply("ReadFromBigQuery",
      BigQueryIO.read(new MyCustomObject1(input))
          .fromQuery(myCustomQuery)
          .usingStandardSql()
  ).apply("ConvertToCsv",
      ParDo.of(new myCustomObject2())
  ).apply("WriteToCSV",
      TextIO.write().to(fileLocation)
          .withSuffix(".csv")
          .withoutSharding()
          .withDelimiter(new char[] {'\r', '\n'})
          .withHeader(csvHeader)
  );
```

but after step 3 (write to GS), i can't add another process to dataflow
how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Because TextIO.write() returns a PDone, instead of a PCollection in the prior PTransform's.

One of the possible solutions in your step 2, you could use a multi out with tags to write to different locations.

```
final TupleTag<String> csvOutTag= new TupleTag<String>(){};
final TupleTag<String> furtherProcessingTag= new TupleTag<String>(){};

PCollectionTuple mixedCollection =    
bigQueryReadCollection.apply(ParDo
            .of(new DoFn<TableRow,String>() {
              @ProcessElement
              public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
                  // Emit to main output, which is the output
                 c.output(c.element().toString());
      
                  // Emit to output with tag furtherProcessing
                  c.output(furtherProcessingTag, c.element());
                }
              }
            }).withOutputTags(csvOutTag,
                    TupleTagList.of(furtherProcessingTag)));

// Get output with tag csvOutTag.
mixedCollection.get(csvOutTag).apply("WriteToCSV",
  TextIO.write().to(fileLocation)
      .withSuffix(".csv")
      .withoutSharding()
      .withDelimiter(new char[] {'\r', '\n'})
      .withHeader(csvHeader));

// Get output with tag furtherProcessingTag.
mixedCollection.get(furtherProcessingTag).apply(...);
```

Please add appropriate data types in TupleTag declaration, based on your output for further processing.